# Spring MVC https how to enable?

Tags: spring, https

In a book it effectively says just add 's' on the end.

All my urls are relative in Controller do I need to make them concrete to use https?

Are my thoughts correct about this issue too?:

If I don't buy certificate then that effectively means the client can't determine who I am(server), but I can still make sure that only this client will get data that is intended for him?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having relative URLs will allow you to serve either http or https.  The new request will honor the scheme of the current request.

Here is the information on configuring tomcat 7 for SSL http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html Other servers should have similar documentation.  You can use a commercial certificate from a known Certificate Authority, or you can self-sign a certificate.  If you self sign, the client will be warned that the certificate is untrusted.  For testing that should be ok.